# Error: GOPATH not set

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to download aws package from github, but I am getting the error...

> Cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath

GO PATH is currently set to $HOME/go

Can anyone explain why it says GOPATH is not set?

Comment: Is the GOPATH really set ? I don't mean "do you think you set the GOPATH ?", but "do `echo $GOPATH` gives you the right value ?".

Comment: @Elwinar: even better, use `go env GOPATH`, since it could be set but not exported.

Comment: I probably have the same issue: `echo $GOPATH` returns what is expected, but `go env GOPATH` is blank. `export GOPATH=$GOPATH` made it work for some reason (which should be an absurd command), but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

Export the go path into terminal

```
export GOPATH=<go path from the Home dir.>
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```